# is it possible to return string in google cloud endpoints python

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I need to return a string (plain text) and not JSON (class message).

here is my code now:

```
    @endpoints.method(
    # This method takes a ResourceContainer defined above.
    Site_resource,
    # This method returns an Echo message.
    Site_response_new,
    path='test',
    http_method='POST',
    name='testsystem')
def testsystem(self, request):
    return Site_response_new(result=data)
```

I want to do :

```
  @endpoints.method(
    # This method takes a ResourceContainer defined above.
    Site_resource,
    # This method returns an Echo message.
    str,
    path='test',
    http_method='POST',
    name='testsystem')
def testsystem(self, request):
    return "awesome string"
```

Thank you<3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible.